# Qt cast with inheritance

Tags: c++, qt

I have the class `Node`

> ```
> class Node : public QObject
> {
> Q_OBJECT
> public:
>     Node(QObject* p) : QObject(p){}
>     void run()
>     {
>        //access to property
>        runImplementtation();
>     }
>     virtual void runImplementation() = 0;
> };
> ```

I have the class `NodeA`

> ```
> class NodeA : public Node
> {
> Q_OBJECT
> Q_PROPERTY(double _a READ a WRITE setA)
> public:
>     NodeA(QObject* p=NULL) : Node(p){}
>     void runImplementation() {}
>     double a() const { return _a; }
>     void setA(double a) { _a = a;}
> private:
> double _a;
> };
> ```

In the function run I would like can manipulate properties of child object. 
If I call the run on NodeA object, in the run method, I can't access to _a property with this->property("_a").

So the solution that I found is :
declare in `Node`
`const QMetaObject * _metaObject;`
and in the constructor of each child class
`_metaObject = metaObject();`

With this, in the run method, I can access to _a property with `_metaObject->cast(this)->property("_a");`.

But, it does not please me to have to do `_metaObject = metaObject();` in constructor of each child class.

Comment: nitpick: QObject should accept a `*QObject p=0`in the constructor that is passed to the super constructor

Comment: Do you try to access it in the `run()` or the `runImplementation()`?

Comment: I call run method which call runImplementation.

Comment: If the property `_a` shall be available for all child classes, define it in the `Node` class directly. If it is only relevant for class `NodeA`, then access it in your `NodeA::runImplementation()` function. If neither applies, then reconsider if inheritance really is the right way to solve your problem. Base classes should never need to know their sub classes.

Comment: The _a property is only relevant for class `NodeA`. The run aims is initialize all inputs of `Node` child then call the specific implementation.

Comment: Calling `Node::run()` will call `NodeA::runImplementation()`, no?

Comment: Initialisation should be done in the constructor so there's not need to initialise all properties in the superclass if they're not relevant to the superclass.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could solve this problem with using virtual functions. For example:

```
class Node : public QObject
{
public:
    [..]
    virtual void run() {...}
    [..]
};
```

and

```
class NodeA : public Node
{
Q_OBJECT
Q_PROPERTY(double _a READ a WRITE setA)
public:
    [..]
    virtual void run()
    {
        // access the _a property with property("_a");
        // The Node::run() also can be called here.
    }
    [..]
};
```

And how to use this:

```
Node *node = new NodeA(...);
node->run(); // will call NodeA::run()
```

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea but I would like generalize as much as possible.